# How to bind Realm objects changes?

Tags: ios, mvvm, realm, reactive-cocoa

In my project im trying to work via MVVM,
so in VM in `.h` file

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray    *cities;
```

in `.m` file

```
  - (NSArray *)cities {
        return [[GPCity allObjects] valueForKey:@"name"];
    }
```

`GPCity` is a `RLMObject` subclass
How to bind this via ReactiveCocoa (i mean see all cities updates/adds/removes) ?

Something like:

```
RAC(self, cities) = [[GPCity allObjects] map:(GPCity *)city {return city.name;}];
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the ReactiveCocoa example in the Realm docs? Maybe you find something there: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/objc/RACTableView

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap Realm change notifications in a RAC signal:

```
@interface RLMResults (RACSupport)
- (RACSignal *)gp_signal;
@end

@implementation RLMResults (RACSupport)
- (RACSignal *)gp_signal {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        id token = [self.realm addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *notification, RLMRealm *realm) {
            if (notification == RLMRealmDidChangeNotification) {
                [subscriber sendNext:self];
            }
        }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [self.realm removeNotification:token];
        }];
    }];
}
@end
```

and then do:

```
RAC(self, cities) = [[[RLMObject allObjects] gp_signal]
                     map:^(RLMResults<GPCity *> *cities) { return [cities valueForKey:@"name"]; }];
```

This will unfortunately update the signal after *every* write transaction, and not just ones which modify cities. Once Realm 0.98 is released with [support for per-RLMResults notifications](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2842), you'll be able to do the following, which will only update when a `GPCity` object is updated:

```
@interface RLMResults (RACSupport)
- (RACSignal *)gp_signal;
@end

@implementation RLMResults (RACSupport)
- (RACSignal *)gp_signal {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        id token = [self addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults *results, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
            }
            else {
                [subscriber sendNext:results];
            }
        }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [token stop];
        }];
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: Very nice example. Exactly what I was looking for. One suggestion. Before the `addNotificationBlock` line, I'd suggest doing a `[subscriber sendNext:self];` to populate the initial value in the signal.